# Unlock Samsung SSD 840 PRO with hdparm

Tags: security, ssd, hdparm

My Samsung SSD 840 PRO is locked with a password set by using the BIOS. Every time I turn on the computer, I have to type in the password. Cause there is a BIOS bug, I am not able to change the password. But I want to remove the password completly.

### I tried to use hdparm for unlocking it, but this step fails:

```
> hdparm -I /dev/sd?

...
Master password revision code 1
     supported
     enabled
     locked
not  frozen
not  expired: security count
...

> hdparm --user-master u --security-unlock PASSWORD /dev/sd?

Issuing SECURITY_UNLOCK command, password="PASSWORD", user=user
SECURITY_ERASE: Input/output error

> hdparm --user-master m --security-unlock PASSWORD /dev/sd?

Issuing SECURITY_UNLOCK command, password="PASSWORD", user=master
SECURITY_ERASE: Input/output error
```

Is it possible to use the hdparm security commands on that drive?

Comment: That's strange. It shouldn't be `locked` after boot if you have successfully unlocked it when the BIOS prompt you for the password. Or have you forgotten the password and skipped unlocking by some means?

Comment: Also did hdparm really give you "SECURITY_ERASE: Input/output error" when you are "Issuing SECURITY_UNLOCK"? What's the version of hdparm you are using?

Comment: Maybe try padding the password with spaces to the maximum length (32 chars). For example, `hdparm --security-unlock "PASSWORD[24 spaces]" /dev/sdX`. Btw when I test on my Intel X25-M SSD, `SECURITY_UNLOCK: Input/output error` is what it gives when I entered a wrong password.

Comment: Tom Yan, I first boot into a live session ubuntu 14.04, then I connect the ssd with the sata port. If the disk is connected while booting, it is not possible to boot without unlocking the disk.

Comment: I also tested the disk on other hardware, where I was asked for the password, but can't unlock. My suggestion is, that the samsung bios, is changing the password in some way. I tested to use scanline codes but had no success. Filling the password up to 32 chars is an idea, I hope to have some time to test it soon.  http://thaeial.blogspot.de/2013/01/locking-and-unlocking-hdd-with-dell.html

Comment: `it is not possible to boot without unlocking the disk` but why not unlocking the disk there?

Comment: Cause I want to remove the password, but I can't use the bios. There is a bug and the disk is always in the frozen state after entering the bios.